# Wide of/off the mark - what's the difference?

Tags: prepositions

When is it OF and when is it OFF?

Your reporter is completely wide **of** the mark in her accusations.

Your reporter is completely wide **off** the mark in her accusations.

I know both are correct. But when are they used?

Answer (score 4):

If I see *wide off the mark*, I assume this is somebody who does not understand the meaning of *wide of* and has emended the expression to something that seems to make more sense to them.

I've looked in several corpora, and the frequency of *wide off the mark* is between 2% and 8% of that of *wide of the mark*.

In short: there is no difference in meaning that I'm aware of, and if I wrote *wide off the mark* that would be an error.

Comment: I can see your point but what shall we do about this https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Off+the+mark

Comment: Look more carefully through the link:  "wide of the mark" and "off the mark" mean similar things, but are alternatives that cannot be mixed together.  These expressions are discussed on the link.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't thought of _off the mark_. That explains how it happens.